# Extremely long delays with in-app purchases

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, swiftystorekit

I'm using SwiftyStoreKit, and lately I'm experiencing extremely long delays with in-app purchases (like, several minutes long).

Often I'm getting something like that:

> Receipt verification failed: networkError(Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1c0245700 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.})

Obviously, recreating all this without SwiftyStoreKit is not a very easy task, so I want to ask beforehand — does anyone else experience something like that with sandbox/production, or if I do it from scratch there is a good chance that all these delays just dissapear?

Comment: I'm using it in my published app and everything works great. I would try to use another validator receipt outside the app (i.e. PHP script) just to test if it is your code or some problem with apple sandbox